# Rails form_authenticity_token doesn't match params[:authenticity_token]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf, csrf-protection

In what situations would the form_authenticity_token not match the params[:authenticity_token] ?

I was seeing unverified requests coming into my app, so I overrode form_tag to print me out some debugging information.

```
form_auth_token:    #{form_authenticity_token.inspect}
session_csrf_token: #{session['_csrf_token'].inspect}
params:             #{params.inspect}
```

And I got output showing that the session had the proper token to match the form_auth_token, but the params submitted authenticity_token didn't match:

```
form_auth_token:    "gckttsVeq2XvTBwQX3BaInWCivIhvR/mYBWjs119eb8="
session_csrf_token: "gckttsVeq2XvTBwQX3BaInWCivIhvR/mYBWjs119eb8="
params:             {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+5IINl7vEh1jJJwP+RiXXws+4kEwM3fpJsCOn+gZ0AA=" ...
```

I thought that by definition the params[:authenticity_token] would be the same as the form_authenticity_token.

1. Am I debugging this the wrong way?
2. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

A few quick suggestions: If you are using the rails jquery helpers, rails will automatically add the csrf-token meta tag value from the head of your HTML document in the POST request. I would check to see what the value is in the `<head>` tag of your HTML document to see if it matches.